# What exactly does the inside of the “Black Lodge” look like in “Twin Peaks?”

Tags: twin-peaks

Yes, there is a new *Twin Peaks* (2017) series. And yes, David Lynch can be obtuse. That said, I rewatched the original series from 1990-91 as well as the feature film prequel, [*Twin Peaks: Fire Walk With Me*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_Peaks:_Fire_Walk_with_Me) (1992) and am a bit confused (please no jokes) about what the inside of the infamous “Black Lodge” looks like.

I understand the entrance is around Glastonbury Grove; pictured below:

[image: “Glastonbury Grove”]

And once someone steps into that realm, the famous red curtained, zig-zagged floor location is known as the “Waiting Room”; pictured below:

[image: “Waiting Room”]

But then what does the actual “Black Lodge” realm look like? Is it the place above the convenience store as shown in [*Fire Walk With Me*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_Peaks:_Fire_Walk_with_Me); pictured below? Or is it something else?

[image: The room above the convenience store.]

Answer (score 1):

Just an opinion here, as it’s very difficult to be factual about parallel dimensions!

I’ve always thought of the Black Lodge as being a mirror world to Earth, a place which births and is home to evil. We have a few glimpses into it across the series, mostly “The Red Room” as shown in your 2nd image. I believe this to be sort of an “entrance lobby” into the Black Lodge. I think this because it is only ever accessed by characters from the same place: Glastonbury Grove.

The rest of it is revealed in brief glimpses, possibly as other “hotspots” around the Earth, where the barriers between the real world and the Black Lodge are thin, such as the often mentioned “Convenience Store,” shown in both [*Twin Peaks: Fire Walk With Me*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_Peaks:_Fire_Walk_with_Me) (1992), and more recently, [*The Return* (Season 3, Part 8)](http://twinpeaks.wikia.com/wiki/Part_8).

Basically I think the set pieces we see throughout the series are “hotspots” around earth which are linked to the Black Lodge. I don’t think the Black Lodge has an “appearance” in the conventional sense; it may not even be physical space.